# Создание задержки в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Как сделать задержку этого фрагмента на 3 секунды через библиотеку pygame?

```
screen.blit(txt1, (0, 50))
screen.blit(txt2, (0, 80))
screen.blit(txt3, (0, 100))
screen.blit(txt4, (0, 120))
screen.blit(txt5, (0, 140))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Смотрите pygame.time.set_timer() <https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer>

Comment: @СергейКох, можете, пожалуйста, показать, как это работает.

Comment: Может это вам поможет <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280545/how-to-use-pygame-time-set-timer-in-pygame>

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.